# Retrieve large amount of data from DB and convert it to Stream

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stream, ado.net

I have a C# application with Entity Framework linked to SQL Server. This application enables client apps to run SQL queries with different parameters each time they're run. The results can go from one to thousand of lines, from a few kB to terabytes of data.

Given that information, the queries are asynchronous and the client apps can retrieve the result whenever they want once the queries are processed. The result must be inserted into another app called `Storage` from my application.

It has a method:

```
Guid PushData(Stream dataStream);
```

to store the query data.

Here is an example of query

```
SELECT @insertedParams FROM schema1.table1;
```

`@insertedParams` could be anything, from a single bit to many different fields. I have simplified the request, the parameters could be anywhere in a query.

**So to sum up:**

- Must run SQL query from C#
- Must retrieve up to terabytes of data with my C# application
- Must convert the data to a stream and send it to another application

If I use Entity Framework, I've tried this:

```
var result = biEasilyContext.Database.SqlQuery<ObjType>(sqlRequest);
```

which returns a `DbRawSqlQuery`. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbsqlquery?view=entity-framework-6.2.0), they say this

> The query is not executed when this object is created; it is executed each time it is enumerated, for example by using foreach.

It makes me think of stream, but not sure and didn't find how to convert it.

I also didn't know what to put instead of `ObjType`.

I might also use ADO.NET like this

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    var command = new SqlCommand(sqlRequest, connection);

    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // Some code?
        }
    }
}
```

I did not find anything else that could help me. Not much help on this subject.

Comment: Is it a single row of a very large blob, or is it many rows of small amounts of data? You probably want to look at `yield return` which would return an `IEnumerable`

Comment: @Charlieface it will mainly be many rows. Each row can have a large amount of data. I'll check the ```yield return``` thank you